# How can I round a TimeObject according to a certain interval

Tags: date-and-time

I have a `TimeObject` for 06:52:24, and I'd like to round it to the nearest 15 minutes (in this case 07:00). Is this possible to do in general? I know how to do it manually, by getting the hour part and then rounding the minutes, but I'm hoping to generalize it to any interval

Comment: Do you actually want rounding (up and down) or do you always want to round up (ceiling function?)

Answer (score 6):

Use `AbsoluteTime` to convert date to seconds since January 1, 1900. Then round to nearest multiple of 15*60 seconds. Convert to a `DateObject` and get just the time by converting to a `TimeObject` and dropping the time zone with `Most`:

```
nearest15[t_] :=
 Module[{abs = AbsoluteTime@t },
  
  Round[abs, 15*60] // DateObject // TimeObject // Most
  
  ]
```

test inputs:

```
t = TimeObject[{6, 52, 24}];
nearest15[t]

(*06:45:00*)
```

Works with both `TimeObject` and `DateObject` inputs:

````
SeedRandom[1234];
rt = RandomTime[]
rd = RandomDate[]

(*"21:02:18

Mon 10 Jul 2023 12:24:24GMT-5
*)

nearest15[rt]
nearest15[rd]


(*"
21:00:00

12:30:00
*)

```
````

Comment: While op said round, his example looks like he actually wants `Ceiling` (06:52:24 should be 07:00)

Answer (score 5):

```
roundTimeObject[minutes_ : 15] := 
  TimeObject[Drop[DateList@Round[AbsoluteTime[#], 60 minutes], 3]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
{t1, t2, t3} = {TimeObject[{6, 52, 24}], 
   TimeObject[{6, 55, 24}], TimeObject[{6, 23, 10}]};
```

Round `t1`, `t2` and `t3` to nearest multiples of 15 minutes, 10 minutes and 15 seconds:

```
Grid[
 Prepend[{"t", "roundTimeObject[]@t",
    "roundTimeObject[10]@t", "roundTimeObject[1/4]@t"}]@
 Map[{#, roundTimeObject[]@#, roundTimeObject[10]@#, roundTimeObject[1/4]@#} &]@
 {t1, t2, t3}, 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]